# Homebrew and mysql unix_socket

Tags: mysql, homebrew, auth-socket

I have installed mysql on my Mac with homebrew
`brew install mysql`
I would like to login to mysql as a root with no password trough auth_socket plugin.
The problem is that there is no auth_socket plugin in **plugin_dir** directory.

I have tried to add in my.cnf

```
plugin-load-add=auth_socket.so
```

And also mysql query:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN auth_socket SONAME 'auth_socket.so';
```

With error "image not found"

How to install auth_socket?

Answer (score 0):

By checking `/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/plugin` ( `/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/plugin` for M1 Mac), brew installed `mysql` doesn't have `auth_socket.so` compiled. So I guess you can't do it.

Comment: Why didn't they compiled it?

Comment: The question is, why didn't they add that auth_socket plugin for Mac M1, is it not useful anymore or what?